# Adding parameter in advanced search that is relative orbite number in SCP plug-in in QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, scp

I would like to add a parameter in my "advanced search", that is "relative orbite number".

How do I do it with this plug-in?

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

[image]